# Running Solr in memory?

Tags: solr

One night I was drinking a pint at a local bar and struck up a conversation with the chap next to me. As it turned out, not only was he a fellow developer, but he also used Solr a lot. As we got to talking about how awesome Solr was, he mentioned something that I've never been able to figure out. He said, "The way to make Solr really perform is to have it run in memory."

Alas, I did not get his name and despite googling for an answer, I've never really found anything concrete. What do you think he meant by this?

Comment: Funny, I just came to the same idea, while being somewhat drunk :-D

Comment: I would still love to see an answer to this question so in development we can use the solr apis with some in-memory implementation like lucene(I don't care about the impl as long as it works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running SOLR in memory is really pointless. SOLR is meant to be a webserver where clients can query using RESTless api. You can set up replication to compensate for high traffic. SOLR wraps Lucene. If you want to run SOLR in memory then you are basically running Lucene in memory. So I would suggest just start an instance of Lucene and have the disk be in memory. I am curious to know what others think but running SOLR in memory is really not intended use. With Lucene there is a [Directory](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/store/Directory.html) implemented in memory called [RAMDirectory](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html).

There was also a similar question a while back about running SOLR embedded mode but after a while Apache deprecated the embedded server stuff because that was really what Lucene was for.

Comment: Same way as MySql can store it's tables and indexes in memory. Being a server has nothing to do with where you store your data.

Comment: I 100% need a in-memory something that runs behind the solr apis for development.  In development we use PlayOrm which runs an in-memory nosql store for our development(so when we restart the server, it is cleared of data....perfect).  We would love to have the same as we use the SOLR apis without doing tons of translation work to adapt to lucene.

Comment: There's a point to it when it would make your tests run a lot faster

Comment: @bcoughlan the question was not about running tests. It was related to running an application in production. If you feel you have a better answer then free to add an answer. Down vote is only justified if the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar There are a few valid use cases for running SOLR in-memory. An example is if you want to have a temporary search index that uses SOLR libs. You can do so with Lucene easily, but it becomes a pain when integrating with both in the event that you have a distributed search across multiple nodes.

If you're wondering why you'd ever want to have a temporary index, think about a sensitive, dynamic data set that you'd never want permanently written to disk. There are other solutions to be sure, but a RAMDirectory-backed SOLR is one way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 12):

For anyone looking to do this for the purpose of speeding up tests:

If you have a separate core for your test index, you can change the `directoryFactory` attribute in `solrconfig.xml` to:

`<directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="solr.RAMDirectoryFactory"/>`

Needless to say, it's not a good idea to keep any production data in memory only.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that he meant having enough disk cache to hold the entire index. That is a widely recommended way of ensuring fast small random IO-reads (and bulk writes when indexing), which is essential for good Solr performance: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems#OS_Disk_Cache

For smaller indexes where the extra RAM cost is relatively low, it is a fine advice. As the indexes grows, it is probably better to invest more time scale-testing and experimenting with other hardware setups, SSDs being an obvious possibility.

Answer (score 0):

While speed is good reason to run a RAMDirectory you'll have to eventually persist the directory to disk.  You probably could write a simple wrapper than wrapped a RAMDirectory and FSDirectory and mirror the calls to both.  All queries would come out of RAMDirectory, but changes would be applied to both.

But another very good reason to do this would be for encryption at rest.  Encrypting data sucks if you actually want to use it because you have to pay the overhead of decrypting to query it.  It's not practical to use encrypted data at rest, but if you decrypted the contents into memory and cached it then it would be very fast.